# Terraform error: does not have attribute 'private_ip' for variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

Using Terraform version 0.11.7 the code below I get this error:

```
    * output.aws_runner_private_ip_addresses: Resource 'aws_spot_instance_request.runner' does not have attribute 'private_ip' for variable 'aws_spot_instance_request.runner.*.private_ip'
    * output.aws_walker_private_ip_addresses: Resource 'aws_spot_instance_request.walker' does not have attribute 'private_ip' for variable 'aws_spot_instance_request.walker.*.private_ip
```

The output syntax looks correct according the documentation from [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html)

And terraform spot instance request does have the attribute of private_ip which is stated in Terraform documentation [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/spot_instance_request.html).

```
resource "aws_spot_instance_request" "walker" {
  count = 2
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  ami = "ami-0922553b7b0369273"
  spot_price = "1"
}

resource "aws_spot_instance_request" "runner" {
  count = 2
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  ami = "ami-0922553b7b0369273"
  spot_price = "1"

}

output "aws_walker_private_ip_addresses" {
    value = ["${aws_spot_instance_request.walker.*.private_ip}"]
}

output "aws_runner_private_ip_addresses" {
    value = ["${aws_spot_instance_request.runner.*.private_ip}"]
}
```

However, if I remove the square brackets from the code, it works and there is no error, but the Terraform document seems to be saying I need to use the square brackets since the value would be a list type of returning list of private_ip addresses for each instance. What am I doing wrong here or misunderstanding?

This works, but seems to contradict the document:

```
output "aws_walker_private_ip_addresses" {
    value = "${aws_spot_instance_request.walker.*.private_ip}"
}

output "aws_runner_private_ip_addresses" {
    value = "${aws_spot_instance_request.runner.*.private_ip}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
wait_for_fulfillment = true
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in the AWS provider for Terraform, similar to [issue #4313](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/4313). I suggest filing a new issue.

I tested your code and found the same issue. However, once I ran `terraform refresh` after the *apply*, the outputs looked fine. 
E.g.:

```
Outputs:

aws_runner_private_ip_addresses = [
  172.31.79.186,
  172.31.71.22
]
aws_walker_private_ip_addresses = [
  172.31.69.119,
  172.31.66.50
]
```

Comment: I tried the 0.11.8 version, but got same result. I wonder if there is a work around?

Comment: If I had to bet, I'd say no. I think it might be quicker and cleaner to submit the bug report. I can't imagine this is a difficult thing to fix.